# buddypress: ещё один способ нотификации

Tags: php, wordpress

У buddypress есть два способа нотификации - системные сообщения и почта. Мне нужно добавить ещё один способ: смс. Нигде в документации о такой возможности не нашёл. Не могли бы подсказать, в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: В сторону сервисов пл отправке sms

Comment: проблема не в отправке собственно смс, а в добавлении ещё одного способа нотификации

Comment: Без сервисов не будет никаких СМС. А у них есть АПИ и др решения с пом которых "способ" добавляется на сайт.

Comment: Я же по-моему ясно сформулировал: как добавить в buddypress третий способ нотификации? Вопрос именно в этом.

Comment: Если ты не понимашь что я пишу - может ну его нафик, это сайтостроение, а..

Comment: я прекрасно понимаю что ты пишешь. Реализовать отправку смс по событию труда не составит. Проблема в том что, как мне кажется, 2 способа нотификаций жестко захардкожены в buddypress. Городить костыли, перехватывая на отправку почты и вместе с ней отправлять смс считаю неправильным. А Вы сударь - хам.